# Example Smart Contract for Staking and Unstaking your own Token

Tags: smart-contract

I'm searching for an example Smart Contract snippet for staking and unstaking a token, for example how KARMA / POKER / DICE are working.

If I stake the token, I'm able to collect dividends. 
If I unstake, I don't get dividends anymore, and the unstaking takes - for example - 24 hours.

Any example contract for staking / unstaking a custom token?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the contract used by eos for this purpose [in the github repository](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/master/eosio.system/src/delegate_bandwidth.cpp).

In this file you can find, for instance, the 72 hours delay defined as `static constexpr time refund_delay = 3*24*3600;` and all the actions and structure needed to [stake](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/7f1aae0f28cf471c24a78a1e1a3b2581444a13c1/eosio.system/src/delegate_bandwidth.cpp#L51-L60) and [unstake](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/7f1aae0f28cf471c24a78a1e1a3b2581444a13c1/eosio.system/src/delegate_bandwidth.cpp#L64-L73) the resources.

Look also at [this article from eoscanada](https://www.eoscanada.com/en/what-does-staking-and-unstaking-eos-tokens-mean).